# Sort products by color in the cart in Magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, sorting, product-sorting

I have configurable products with virtual variations by color and size.

In the cart, I am trying to arrange them in the order of priority, by configurable parent, then by color, then by size.

In my ovverriden cart template, I am calling the cart items like this :

```
if ($block->getItemsCount()) {
    if($cartItems = $block->getQuote()->getAllItems()){
        if($confId = $product->getId()){
            $configQty = $v->getQty();
            if($product){
                /* the logic */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the admin "**Stores >> Configuratin >> Sales >> Checkout >> Configurable Product Image**"  I have activated "**Product Thumbnail Itself**", to have the individual image Swatches of each virtual Variation.

Could you tell me what I should do in order to get the products collection sorted by '**color**', please?

Here is the code that I have in a separate file at the root of my project:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
class TestApp 
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface, \Magento\Framework\AppInterface{
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
            SortOrder $sortOrder,
            SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteriaInterface
    ){
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend'); // or 'adminhtml', depending on your needs
        $this->_sortOrder = $sortOrder;
        $this->_searchCriteriaInterface = $searchCriteriaInterface;
    }
    public function getCurrentPage(){}
    public function setCurrentPage($currentPage){}
    public function getFilterGroups(){}
    public function setFilterGroups(array $filterGroups = NULL){}
    public function getSortOrders(){}
    public function setSortOrders(array $sortOrders = NULL){}
    public function getPageSize(){}
    public function setPageSize($currentPage){}
    protected function getSearchCriteria(){
        $searchcriteriaint = $this->_searchCriteriaInterface;
        $searchcriteriaint->setSortOrders(array($this->getSortOrder()));
        return $searchcriteriaint;
    }
    protected function getSortOrder(){
        $sortorder = $this->_sortOrder;
        $sortorder->setField('color')->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
        return $sortorder;
    }
    public function launch(){
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        // // get quote items collection
        // $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        // // get array of all items what can be display directly
        $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems($this->getSearchCriteria());
        foreach($items as $key => $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $_product = $item->getProduct();
            $product = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
            echo 'Type: '.$item->getProductType().'<br/>';
            echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br/>';
            echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br/>';
            echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br/>';
            echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br/>';
            echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br/>';
            echo "<br />";
        }
        // return $this->_response;
    }
    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Don't hesitate to point out good vs bad practice.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `SearchInterface` to sort things by a certain value.

**You will need to edit the Block function getAllItems**
(if you don't know how to do this i can provide more information , just ask)

```
    use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface
    use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;

        protected $_sortOrder;
        protected $_searchCriteriaInterface;

    public function __construct(
            SortOrder $sortOrder,
            SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteriaInterface
    ){
            $this->_sortOrder = $sortOrder;
            $this->_searchCriteriaInterface = $searchCriteriaInterface;
    }

    protected function getSearchCriteria(){

      $searchcriteriaint = $this->_searchCriteriaInterface;
      $searchcriteriaint->setSortOrders(array($this->getSortOrder()))

return $searchcriteriaint;
    }

protected function getSortOrder()
    {
        $sortorder = $this->_sortOrder;

        $sortorder
            ->setField('color')
            ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);

        return $sortorder;
    }
```

**And wherever your items are getting called you need to adjust it to something like this :**

```
public function getProductList()
{

    $products = $this->_productRepository->getList($this->getSearchCriteria());

    return $products;

}
```

Hope this helps.

If you need more information i will need the file path that you are adjusting and which block/xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot and please, explain.

In "public function getProductList($value)"

What is $value?

Comment: I editted it. it was a copy paste from something that i use and i use that to set something in the searchcritiria , you can just ignore it

Comment: You just need the getlist function from whatever you are calling and put the searchcriteria in it

Comment: Please, explain how to implement it in the block. What block and how should I override in my module to have it work on the 'checkout/cart' page?

I do not have '$this->_productRepository->' 

My ' $products = $block->getQuote()->getAllItems() ' is an array.

When I do ' $block->getQuote()->getList($this->getSearchCriteria()) ', I get :

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getList() on array...

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Like i said you will need to override your block class and not your block template. You will need to create a new function within your new block class. If this all does not make any sense to you then you are new to templating. In that case i will need to know what you have in which location to help you out

Comment: Please specify the steps in rewriting the standard Magento2.1.9 Cart in a custom module "Myvendorname/Mymodulename" so that the " $products = $this->_productRepository->getList " works in the cart. I imagine that some more dependencies must be imported. " $cartItems = $block->getQuote()->getAllItems() " is an array of objects. Can " $this->getSearchCriteria() " work on it?

Comment: Supersonic please... I'm trying to help here. Update your question with the filles that you have and the code that you are currently using (xml's , php filles ..) and i will edit that for you so it works. it is the last time that i do this request that you give me something to work with.

Comment: "SwAt.Be" , thanks for your help, but you are in a wrong scope. I am working on the Quote Object. In "vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php" in the "public function getAllVisibleItems()" i added "$this->getItemsCollection()->setOrder('sku','asc')" instead of "$this->getItemsCollection()" and the cart items that I call with "$block->getQuote()->getItemsCollection()" get sorted.

Comment: Hi Swat.Be! I have tried some more and different code, which I added to the question, could you have a look and tell me what is missing/wrong? Thanks a lot!