# Magento2 - Need to change order Item by Price in email

Tags: magento2, cart, email, order-email

I need to customize order Email to display items order by High to Low price. But unable to find the exact file for this.

Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure , but i think if you sort products by price in cart they will be sorted in email also. You can test it at least.
Check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197997/sort-products-by-color-in-the-cart-in-magento2) to implement price sorting (**there is example with color**)